# Appending string2 to string1 in C throws segmentation fault

Tags: c

Iam trying to reproduce the behaviour of strlcat in C,writing my own function.

I need to append string1 to the end of string2.

I start looping through string1 until it finds a '\0', and then I try to write string2 to string1 from there. However I think this is not the way to do it because it throw some segmentation fault and maybe Im acessing memor I shouldn't (?).

```
char *ft_srlcat(char *dst, char *src, int size) {
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (dst[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    
    while (size > 0 || src[j] != '\0')
    {
        dst[i] = src[j];
        i++;
        j++;
        size--;
    }
    printf("%s\n", dst);
}
```

```
void main { 
    ft_strlcat("A very long", "teste to see if it works"), 5
}
```

Comment: Also, `size` is likely supposed to mean the entire buffer size, and you're decrementing it only for the `src` part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776005/appending-strings-in-c)

Comment: You can't modify string constants, this causes SEGFAULT.

Comment: Technically incorrect, @AR7CORE. The behavior is undefined. A segfault is _likely_ but not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the correct type for sizes (size_t)
2. `size` to make any sense should indicate the `dst` array length
3. You cant call this function if `dst` is not modifiable (const array for example)
4. When you define function as returning something - return it.
5. Your function is not null terminating the string if the array is not big enough to accommodate both strings

```
char *ft_srlcat(char *dst, char *src, size_t size)
{
    char *wrk = size ? dst : NULL;
    if(dst && src)
    {
        while (*dst && size) {dst++; size--;}            
        while (size > 1 && (*dst++ = *src++)) size--;
        if(!size && !*dst) *dst = 0;
    }
    return wrk;
}


int main(void)
{
    char dest[15] = "Hello world.";
    char dest2[5] = "Hello world.";
    char dest1[128] = "Hello world.";
    char dest3[0] = "Hello world.";

    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(dest, "Goodbye", sizeof(dest)));
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(dest2, "Goodbye", sizeof(dest2)));
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(dest1, "Goodbye", sizeof(dest1)));
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(dest3, "Goodbye", sizeof(dest3)) ? dest3 : "NULL");
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(dest1, NULL, sizeof(dest3)) ? dest3 : "NULL");
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat(NULL, "Goodbye", sizeof(dest3)) ? dest3 : "NULL");
    printf("`%s`\n", ft_srlcat("Hello world.", "Goodbye", sizeof("Hello world.")));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6xGafsjjo