# Saving multiple chars in pointer C (dynamic memory)

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic, char

I need to create mini social network in C. I made a `struct` for each person. And I'm storing each friend in a `char` pointer with id's. I thought I can manage it like this:

```
ptr_friends = id1,id2,id3,id4...
```

and when I need them I could just read those by using `strtok`.

But I couldn't manage to save it that way. It should be like this:

```
ptr_friends = ptr_friends + id + ","
```

but of course it doesn't work this why and I don't know how to do it.

How can I save and use this way? Or if you have another idea for a save method please tell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show some source code that you tried. And read some C language tutorial!

Comment: take a look at `strcat()`  -- http://bit.ly/18TqzP1

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you make `ptr_friends` a pointer to multiple chars by using `malloc(size_t)` and then resizing the space with `realloc(void *, size_t)` everytime you want to add an ID to the friendlist. That way you can just get the numbers using `ptr_friends[i]`.

For example :

```
int friends_size = 1;

char *ptr_friends = malloc((size_t)1);

ptr_friends[0] = john_id; // john_id is a fictional ID here
```

And when you want to add a friend :

```
ptr_friends = realloc(ptr_friends, ++friends_size);
ptr_friends[friends_size-1] = mary_id;
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to make a function to add a friend, for example `addfriend(char *,int)`, doing the following is an error :

```
void addfriend(char *ptr_friends, int *friends_size, int id)
{
    ptr_friends = realloc(ptr_friends, (size_t) ++(*friends_size));
    ptr_friends[friends_size-1] = id;
}
```

`ptr_friends` here is getting reallocated, and since the pointer can move while being reallocated, we're storing it in `ptr_friends`. But, it's the `ptr_friends` from **inside** the function, that means that the pointer we give to the function will **not** get modified, since arguments to a function are **copied** elsewhere beforehand. That means that you have to give a pointer to the pointer, so you can modify the pointer in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901241/2549281

You should use something like :

```
strcat(ptr_friends, id);
strcat(ptr_friends, ",");
```

instead of ptr_friends + id + ","

Answer (score 0):

Would not it be easier to you to do an array of ints with ids?

```
int max_friends  = 50;
int friends_size = 0;
int friends*     = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_FRIENDS);
friends[friens_size] = id;
friends_size++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is instead of using a string or a simple array you can use a "generic" dynamic array (using void*). It's a simple code and you can find many examples.

take a look at that question: [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)