# C Programming: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant

Tags: c, syntax

```
shell_command(char gcommand[100]) {
 char output[100];
 system(gcommand ">" output);

 return output;
}
```

Gives me 
**error: expected ‘)’ before string constant**

I am not quite sure why this happens. Appriciate any help :)

Comment: What are you expecting `system(gcommand ">" output);` to do? It's simply wrong C. Fix that and I bet you that your problem will disappear

Comment: That isn't how you appends strings, see this answer on how to do that in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901181/c-string-append

Comment: I think he's trying to pipe into a C array from a system command? That doesn't work either.

Comment: `output` is a empty string at best and garbage at worst. What's the purpose of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals can be concatenated like that, but string values cannot.

Further, it seems that you want the output of `gcommand` to end up in the buffer `output`.

It is not possible to do that with the `system` function. Assuming you are going to be executing in a POSIX-style shell where `>` is the shell redirection operator, the thing to the right of it must be a *file name* (or descriptor) in the shell.

To execute a command and capture the output, one way is to use the POSIX [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) function:

```
FILE *pipe = popen(gcommand, "r");
char output[100] = { 0 };

if ( pipe )
{
    fgets(output, sizeof output, pipe);
    pclose(pipe);
}

return output;
```