# "How to pass String value in between URL in C/C++?"

Tags: c++

I've one variable in which i get string value from user.
Now i want to use that string value in URL.
like my string value is "Indore". so it should pass like
URL="awe/Indore/ddsd".
Please tell me how to solve?

Comment: Neither c nor c++ have a basic notion of URLs. It's completely unclear what you're asking about, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried already? How did it go and what error messages did you receive?

Comment: Your question is absolutely vague, but I guess you should take a look at `strcat` method

Comment: @Bond Maybe `std::regex` can provide you with some useful operations to insert to the URL that you finally need.

Comment: @Bond Your question is just as unclear as ever. Please add clarifications to the question itself, along with example code showing what you have tried.

Comment: I just want to clarify. 
I've one variable var1 which gets value from user. e.g. var1 = "Russia" and i've another variable var2="Capital/Japan". 

Output should be "Capital/Russia/Japan" 

Note : I used c_str() but got below mentioned output:
"Capital/var1.c_str()/Japan" instead of "Capital/Russia/Japan".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first we need to know what "String" type are you working with and maybe provide examples so that we can better help you. From what I see from your comment, you can split the string first then merge them together.

If it is a C string `char*` then you can use `strtok` to split (see [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)). Then merge with `strcat` as [Ehsan Khodarahmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183652/ehsan-khodarahmi) mentioned, (see [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901181/c-string-append))

If it is a `std::string` string, then you can try my implementation in c++ for splitting `std::string` string.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string inputString, std::string delimiter){
    std::string temp = inputString;
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    while ((pos = temp.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = temp.substr(0, pos);
        output.push_back(token);
        temp.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    output.push_back(temp);
    return output;
}
```

In your case, you can do

```
std::vector<std::string> splitted = spitString("Capital/Madhya", "/");
```

Then `splitted = {"Capital", "Madhya"}`, and you can just do

```
std::string url = splitted[0] + "/Indore/" + splitted[1];
```

As people said in the comment, your question is vague, so my answer may not directly help you.

**Update**

If you are using `c_str()` then you are probably using `std::string`. `c_str()` is used for converting `std::string` to c string `char*` (see [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)). So in this case, you can use my code provided to assist you. From what you told me, user input was passed to `var1`.

```
std::string var1 = "Russia"
```

And you already have `var2`

```
std::string var2 = "Capital/Japan"
```

Then simply split the `var2` by `/` and merge what you want.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitted = splitString(var2, "/");
std::string result = splitted[0] + "/" + var1 + "/" + splitted[1];
```

Then your result should be "Capital/Russia/Japan".

**Update2**

First, thanks for include code this time. You should do that all the time if possible so people know what to work with.
Note: To format your code, enclose your code with ```

Now to your question. You provided this

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    std::string var1 = "Russia"; 
    std::string var2 = "Capital/Japan"; 
    std::vector<std::string> splitted = splitString(var2, "/"); 
    std::string result = splitted[0] + "/" + var1 + "/" + splitted[1]; 
    cout<<result; return 0; 
}
```

And your compiler doesn't like it and says

```
error: 'splitString' was not declared in this scope
```

This error message basically says that `splitString` function does not exist. This is because you did not include my code in your code. At some point you will get more comfortable reading these error messages.

So the fix is

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string inputString, std::string delimiter){
    std::string temp = inputString;
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    while ((pos = temp.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = temp.substr(0, pos);
        output.push_back(token);
        temp.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    output.push_back(temp);
    return output;
}

int main() { 
    std::string var1 = "Russia"; 
    std::string var2 = "Capital/Japan"; 
    std::vector<std::string> splitted = splitString(var2, "/"); 
    std::string result = splitted[0] + "/" + var1 + "/" + splitted[1]; 
    cout<<result; return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I just want to clarify. 
I've one variable var1 which gets value from user. e.g. var1 = "Russia" and i've another variable var2="Capital/Japan". 

Output should be "Capital/Russia/Japan" 

Note : I used c_str() but got below mentioned output:
"Capital/var1.c_str()/Japan" instead of "Capital/Russia/Japan".

Comment: Please check me updated answer.

Comment: Code is :
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 std::string var1 = "Russia";
 std::string var2 = "Capital/Japan";
 

 std::vector<std::string> splitted = splitString(var2, "/");
    std::string result = splitted[0] + "/" + var1 + "/" + splitted[1];
    
    cout<<result;
 
 return 0;
}

But getting below mentioned error:
prog.cpp:10:59: error: 'splitString' was not declared in this scope
  std::vector<std::string> splitted = splitString(var2, "/");
                                                                                    ^

Comment: Please check me updated answer.